# AS3: Touch event problem with drag and drop objects

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, touch-event, android-touch-event

I'm new to AS3 and I'm making a drag and drop game with touch events. I'm having problems with the drag and drop objects. My objects are movie clips so there's answer1_mc, answer2_mc, and answer3_mc. When I do a test run, if i click on them for the second time, an error pops up (see the attached image below).

I need the movie clips to not have errors when I tap them more than once.
Please help me :((

```html
//DRAG AND DROP OBJECTS

var answer1PosX: Number = answer1_mc.x;
var answer1PosY: Number = answer1_mc.y;
var answer2PosX: Number = answer2_mc.x;
var answer2PosY: Number = answer2_mc.y;
var answer3PosX: Number = answer3_mc.x;
var answer3PosY: Number = answer3_mc.y;

answer1_mc.buttonMode = true;
answer2_mc.buttonMode = true;
answer3_mc.buttonMode = true;

answer1_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
answer2_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
answer3_mc.gotoAndStop(1);

check_btn.visible = false;
var dragbounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);


answer1_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchgo1);
function touchgo1(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, dragbounds);
    answer1_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    answer2_mc.x = answer2PosX;
    answer2_mc.y = answer2PosY;
    answer3_mc.x = answer3PosX;
    answer3_mc.y = answer3PosY;
}

answer1_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchno1);
function touchno1(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
    answer1_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    if (answer1_mc.answer1_txt.text == sum) {
        correct_answer = true;
    } else {
        correct_answer = false;
    }
    if (answer1_mc.hitTestObject(answerbox_mc)) {
        answer1_mc.x = answerbox_mc.x;
        answer1_mc.y = answerbox_mc.y;
        check_btn.visible = true;
        answer2_mc.x = answer2PosX;
        answer2_mc.y = answer2PosY;
        answer3_mc.x = answer3PosX;
        answer3_mc.y = answer3PosY;
    } else {
        answer1_mc.x = answer1PosX;
        answer1_mc.y = answer1PosY;
        check_btn.visible = false;
    }
}


answer2_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchgo2);
function touchgo2(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, dragbounds);
    answer2_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    answer1_mc.x = answer1PosX;
    answer1_mc.y = answer1PosY;
    answer3_mc.x = answer3PosX;
    answer3_mc.y = answer3PosY;
}

answer2_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchno2);
function touchno2(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
    answer2_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    if (answer2_mc.answer2_txt.text == sum) {
        correct_answer = true;
    } else {
        correct_answer = false;
    }
    if (answer2_mc.hitTestObject(answerbox_mc)) {
        answer2_mc.x = answerbox_mc.x;
        answer2_mc.y = answerbox_mc.y;
        check_btn.visible = true;
        answer1_mc.x = answer1PosX;
        answer1_mc.y = answer1PosY;
        answer3_mc.x = answer3PosX;
        answer3_mc.y = answer3PosY;
    } else {
        answer2_mc.x = answer2PosX;
        answer2_mc.y = answer2PosY;
        check_btn.visible = false;
    }
}

answer3_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchgo3);
function touchgo3(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, dragbounds);
    answer3_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    answer2_mc.x = answer2PosX;
    answer2_mc.y = answer2PosY;
    answer1_mc.x = answer1PosX;
    answer1_mc.y = answer1PosY;
}

answer3_mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchno3);
function touchno3(event: TouchEvent): void {
    event.target.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
    answer3_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    if (answer3_mc.answer3_txt.text == sum) {
        correct_answer = true;
    } else {
        correct_answer = false;
    }
    if (answer3_mc.hitTestObject(answerbox_mc)) {
        answer3_mc.x = answerbox_mc.x;
        answer3_mc.y = answerbox_mc.y;
        check_btn.visible = true;
        answer2_mc.x = answer2PosX;
        answer2_mc.y = answer2PosY;
        answer1_mc.x = answer1PosX;
        answer1_mc.y = answer1PosY;
    } else {
        answer3_mc.x = answer3PosX;
        answer3_mc.y = answer3PosY;
        check_btn.visible = false;
    }
}
```

`

[This is the error popping up when a choice is tapped for the second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzSWA.png)

Comment: try event.currentTarget instead of event.target in your event handlers